# Java pattern recognition API for stock market

Tags: java, api, finance, stock, pattern-recognition

Does someone know where I can find a Java API dealing with pattern recognition for the financial market ? I've already had a look to TA_LIB, but it's not exactly doing what I want (dealing mostly with Japanese Candle pattern whereas I would prefer general pattern).

Comment: Google for "vodoo technical analysis", you'll find lots of useful libraries.

Comment: Thanks, did that but did not find anything relevant... A lot of crap articles appears in the search result, even when refining with terms like "API", "Java"

Comment: What do you mean by pattern recognition? Do you mean something like a classifier for a head and shoulders pattern? More specifics would be great.

Comment: Hi Steeve, yes exactly that kind of stuff, dead cat bouncing, head and shoulder, cross etc...

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen Weka API? It's data mining program written in Java for finding some patterns in your data: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I did have a look to weka but it seemed to me at that time that it was quite complicated and too generic compared to what I aiming to do and the very specific nature of the programm. But I will revisit the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at doing this once at a hedge fund to take advantage of technical traders. There were not good sets of training data available to train classifiers. There are no libraries that I know of that do this.

I would recommend using actual pattern recognition, for instance mean reverting strategies. For a starter paper on statistical arbitrage see [this paper](http://math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/AvellanedaLeeStatArb071108.pdf). The difficulty with technical analysis patterns is that for anything sophisticated it can be difficult to build a set of features that allow the different patterns to be recognized differentiated. Most patterns have visual and not mathematical definitions. If you can come up with an algorithm to find a particular pattern then you will be in good shape, although it will not be easy. I do know that many automated algorithms do compute support/resistance levels to get a rough idea of what technical traders will be looking at.

Answer (score -1):

A good and very sound entry point is **Symbolic Aggregate approXimation (SAX)** and **SAX-VSM** for Java. See [The SAX Homepage](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/SAX.htm) for details. While the available software does not do what you want out of the box, it is very robust and avoids many pitfalls, because it was created on a foundation where it was recognized that clustering does NOT work at all for pattern recognition. SAX can encode a pattern that you draw and then search a time series for it. On the other hand, as many people have discovered, pattern recognition does not result in predictive value and cannot be used for financial gain. To see the results of a system that has been exposed as a scam, a system that has been sold by a charlatan for decades with wild claims, check out [The Reversal System - Engineering Perspective](https://armstrongecmscam.blogspot.com/p/the-reversal-system-engineering.html) and related pages. It is relevant because it uses pattern recognition to look up support and resistance values in a financial time series.